# Why the questions of which an answer has been accepted won't be close automatically?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

In my opinion. If one accepted an answer, he or she would not expect more answers. Why not close this question automatically?

Comment: What good would come from your proposal? You provided no argument,

Comment: This runs against the core ideas of SE network. The questions and answers are viewed as part of a repository. With future improvements always welcome.  May be you thought that closing a question is something like when detectives "close a case"? Closing a question carries the meaning that there is something wrong with the question. It is on its way to deletion, unless it is improved by somebody.

Comment: If automatic closure is implemented, what if a wrong answer is accepted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because many times you can get a better answer, you can get more answers, you can change your mind and decide that one answer is better than the others.

Because the questions are also for [future] readers, which might come from a different context and a different answer might be useful to them as well, or they might have some different idea.

Because this site, ultimately is a site for asking questions and having a repository of plausible answers.